# Manim: Change size of text after creation

Tags: python, animation, manim

```
class Bla(Scene):
  def construct(self):
    t = Text("Hello world")
    self.add(t)
    self.wait()
    t.size = 100
    self.wait(2)
```

I know that `color` is a parameter for the constructor, but how can I change this attribute after the text is already created?

For me, running this class leaves the text fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `scale` function to resize it after creation:

```
class Blah(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        t = Text("Hello world")
        self.add(t)
        self.wait()
        self.play(t.animate.scale(2))
        self.wait(2)
```

[image]